# Changing child's text color of expandable list

Tags: android, eclipse, colors

I have reviewed previous questions and I have tried every solution that has been provided but nothing seems to be working with me, I have an expandable list and I want to set the text color for the child elements to white (not transparent, plain white), this is the code I have:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = getGenericView();
    textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
    textView.setTextColor(color.white);
    return textView;
}
```

I also tried:
`textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));`

But when I run the application, the text is never displayed (I am not sure if it's making it transparent).

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful for you to post links to the solutions you mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color is a class. Use

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.white);
```

instead of

```
textView.setTextColor(color.white);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about it being transparent, pass a  hex value of `0xFFFFFFFF` corresponding to non-transparent white instead of `color.white`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hex value instead.

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

I've used the parseColor method which converts hex to a valid color..

[parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29)